# Writing to file using overloaded operator << - problem with recursion

Tags: c++

I´m currently learning C++ and I decided to try to write my own "log tool". My goal is, that I can write just something like this:

```
logger<<"log message";
```

I have this problem - when I wrote operator << overloading function, the IDE compiler warned me, that it is infinite recursion.

Here is the code of operator overloading:

```
Logger &operator<<(Logger &logger, char *message)
{

logger << message << "Log message";

return logger;
}
```

And function is in class declared as friend:

```
friend Logger &operator<<(Logger &logger, char *message);
```

Why is this code infinite recursion? Maybe I just can´t see some trivial mistake...

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to invoke your overloaded `operator<<` from anywhere, you need a `Logger` object on the left side and a `char*` pointer (BTW, it should be `const char*` instead) on the right side.

Inside your overloaded `operator<<`, this statement:

`logger << message`

is trying to invoke an `operator<<` with a `Logger` object on the left side and a `char*` pointer on the right side.

So, what do you think that is going to invoke? That's right, ITSELF! Over and over, endlessly, forever.  That is what the compiler is warning you about.

You need to replace `logger` in that statement with whatever `std::istream` (or other object) that the `Logger` class wants to write to. Not the `Logger` itself.

For example, let's say your `Logger` class has a data member named `m_file`. Your overloaded `operator<<` could then look like this:

```
Logger& operator<<(Logger &logger, const char *message)
{
    logger.m_file << message << "Log message";
    return logger;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the recursion explanation. The way you suggest seem good, just one question - I cannot create ostream object, since its constructor is protected. My idea was to use reference somehow. 
I´m sorry, I´m learning this for a short time...I still don´t know much.

Comment: Using a reference (or a pointer) only makes sense if your Logger can write to any type of ostream descendant the caller wants. But, if it is specific to just writing to a file stream, as your original question suggests, then use ofstream instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
Logger &operator<<(Logger &logger, char *message)
```

This declares an `operator<<` overload. It takes a left-hand side parameter that's a `Logger &`, and a right-hand side parameter that's a `char *`, that's what this means in C++.

```
logger << message
```

And this invokes the `<<` operator. Amongst all the defined operator overloads for `<<`, there is one operator overload that will work here: this particular operator overload takes a left-hand side parameter that's a `Logger &` -- and this `logger` object meets this criteria smashingly well -- and a right-hand side parameter that's a `char *` -- that's equally met well by the `message` object.

In other words, this calls the same `operator<<` overload, hence the infinite recursion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...but unfortunately, I´m afraid I don´t understand. It is still a very new concept for me...and language as well. I don´t have defined any other operator overloads. This is the only one.

Comment: What Sam means is Inside `Logger &operator<<(Logger &logger, char *message)` you have `logger << message` which will call `Logger &operator<<(Logger &logger, char *message)`. Inside the function that handles `logger <<message` you cannot `logger << message`.